# Spring Boot, Spring ORM, JPA and Hibernate do not create tables automatically with as400 bd2

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am working in a little proyect with Spring boot. I desire to develop an application with Spring ORM, JPA, Hibernate and Db2 as400.

I have already done the test with Apache Derby and the ORM (create the entity -> tables) and it works well, but when I try to use as400 (db2) and wrote the follow properties in the application.properties the ORM does not work (it does not create tables).

```
# ===============================
# = DATA SOURCE
# ===============================
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:as400://serverIP/Squema
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.password=pass
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCDriver
# ===============================
# = JPA / HIBERNATE
# ===============================
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.DB2400Dialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
```

If I omited the "JPA / Hibernate" properties in the application.properties file and I create manually tables, the application work well, but if I dont have  tables in the data base and pretend creates with spring ORM, I get the next mistake:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
```

Does Someone know the cause?

Comment: when you look at the log.. at what sql statement does the logging stop? Also isnt there any more detailed info in the full stack trace?

Comment: The solution is:
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

Ref:
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html